# Microsoft Graph curl to Excel online

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have an Excel on-line spreadsheet. It's sits on my company's OneDrive.
I'd like to ask is it possible to get value of the specific cell (with formula in it) using Microsoft Graph and simple curl from bash?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. It is possible to get value of the specific cell (with formula in it) using Microsoft Graph and simple curl from bash.

Try the following [endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/excel):

> GET
>   /{version}/me/drive/items/{item-id}/workbook/worksheets/{worksheet-id}/range(address='A1:B2')
>   authorization: Bearer {access-token}  workbook-session-id:
>   {session-id}

My test request endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/test.xlsx:/workbook/mysheet/range(address='c1')
```

Response

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#workbookRange",
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.workbookRange",
    "@odata.id": "/me/drive/root/workbook/worksheets(guid)/range(address=%27c1%27)",
    "address": "Sheet1!C1",
    "addressLocal": "Sheet1!C1",
    "cellCount": 1,
    "columnCount": 1,
    "columnHidden": false,
    "columnIndex": 2,
    "formulas": [
        [
            "=SUM(D1,E1)"
        ]
    ],
    "formulasLocal": [
        [
            "=SUM(D1,E1)"
        ]
    ],
    "formulasR1C1": [
        [
            "=SUM(RC[1],RC[2])"
        ]
    ],
    "hidden": false,
    "numberFormat": [
        [
            "General"
        ]
    ],
    "rowCount": 1,
    "rowHidden": false,
    "rowIndex": 0,
    "text": [
        [
            "3"
        ]
    ],
    "values": [
        [
            3
        ]
    ],
    "valueTypes": [
        [
            "Double"
        ]
    ]
}
```